# Let $Z$ be a positive random variable. Find $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{E[Z^{n+1}]}{ (n+1)E[Z^n]}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose that $Z$ is a positive random variable.  I am interested in whether the following limits characterizes some properties of the distribution of $Z$:
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{E[Z^{n+1}]}{ (n+1)E[Z^n]}
\end{align}

For example, we know that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} E^{1/n}[Z^n]$ characterizes the essential supremum.

**What I have done.**   I have a feeling that it characterized some kind of tail behavior.
For example, if $Z$ is bounded by $A$ then it can be shown that the limit is equal zero:
\begin{align*} 
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{E[Z^{n+1}]}{ (n+1)E[Z^n]}  \le  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ A E[Z^{n}]}{ (n+1)E[Z^n]} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ A }{ (n+1)} =0. 
\end{align*}

More generally, I found the following behavior. Suppose that $Z \sim e^{-z^k}$, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{E[Z^{n+1}]}{ (n+1)E[Z^n]}= \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 
0& k>1\\
1& k=1\\
\infty & 0<k<1
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m(t) = E(e^{tZ}) = \sum_k a_k t^k$ be the [moment generating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) function of $Z$. Your limit is $\lim_k \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$, i.e. you are applying the ratio test for convergence.

Essentially $m(t)$ is expected to exist on an interval $(-L,L)$ where $L^{-1}$ is your limit.

Comment: Just to get it right.  $L$ radius of convergence of the moment generating function of $Z$, right? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, since $a_k = E(Z^k)/k!$.

Comment: Ok.  This very clear.  I was expecting such a simple answer.  Thank you!